# Unexpected identifier '_classCallCheck'. Import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babel-loader

Unexpected identifier '_classCallCheck'.import call expects exactly one argument.
Problem with React Native. I tried everythig from google, but it didn't work. **How can I update babel-preset-expo?**

Answer (score 0):

Just check your node version,
Uninstall Node,
Reinstall the same version Node,
RESTART YOUR COMPUTER!